# Devanagari font rendering in Windows Phone, incorrect character sequence

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts, internationalization, hindi

I am developing an application that translates English text into Hindi using Microsoft Translation Service.
I am using TextBlock control to display translation results.

The translated text in Hindi character sequence is incorrect.
For instance the Translation for a word 'heart' is ' दिल ' 
However the character sequence is incorrect and it is displayed as ' [translation for word 'Heart' into Hindi](http://sdrv.ms/TYFOu2)

I am unable to figure out the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case still struggling...

How is दिल stored in memory for your app? Is it following Unicode sequence \u0926, \u093f, \u0932? Which font are you using for presentation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem existed in Windows Phone 7.0 version. I have updated the application to Windows Phone 7.1 and it is now working fine.

Thank you Amir E. Aharoni and Sabinia.